# Workaround for compiler error when storing large arrays of strings

Tags: ios, arrays, string, swift, compiler-errors

When I'm trying to build my app, I get a compiler error saying:

> Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

because I have a array of around 3000 strings directly in my code.

Does anyone have have a workaround for this? Can I somehow save my strings in a .txt-file and just retrieve it as it is. I created my string in Java so it's already in the correct format:

```
["String1", "String2", "String3"]
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557581/command-failed-due-to-signal-segmentation-fault-11

Comment: @JustinLardinois I read that post, but it didn't help. My main problem is that the compiler just can't process the large array I have, to I ultimately need a workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking for a work-around there is only one solution: you need to reduce the array to smaller size and join it programmatically.

As a side note: I got the SEGM 11 after a temp installation of XCode beta and got rid of that only after

```
rm -rf  ~/Library/Developer/Xcode
```