# Segmentation Fault 11 After Updating XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

After I updated to XCode 7.0.1, I am getting this error:

> Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

I am coding in Swift. I have tried emptying the derived data and cleaning the project, but the project won't build. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: if you double tap on the error and read through the entire error log, it should tell you the file that is causing this problem

Comment: I tried doing that and looking through that file but it didn't fix anything. Any other suggestions?

Comment: it should give you a detail in that error of where the problem is, post the full error

Comment: If you are using the **Parse SDK**, this might be your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557581/command-failed-due-to-signal-segmentation-fault-11/32866323#32866323