# xCode Build Failed: Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6, swift2

I'm getting an error in xCode stating:

```
Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11
```

The line is occuring on line 55:

```
While emitting SIL for 'saveScore' at /Users/mobiledev/Desktop/Salt Armour App/SADiver/SADiver/objGameOver.swift:55:2
```

...and line 55 is:

```
    func saveScore()
```

However I still have no idea what can be done to resolve this.

### Full Source:

http://pastebin.com/LUvLaARJ

P.S.

I found two other articles related to this error on SO - however neither scenario seems to apply here :/

Any input/suggestions/tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your pastebin does not seem to be complete. Line 133 is missing a method. Other than that, I can't seem to find anything special in your code. Try doind a clean and rebuild?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557581/command-failed-due-to-signal-segmentation-fault-11)