# Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 (Only Sometimes)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segmentation-fault

My problem is that I tried all solutions given for to solve this error, but I am not getting a proper solution.

In my case, sometimes when I clean my project and try to build it will work. but sometimes not. I also have set Enable BitCode to No.

[image: Error While Building]

After cleaning (Mac + Shift + K) (only works sometimes, not every time.)

[image: same Project Build successfully]

How do I fix this? I am using Firebase in my Project.

Edited: Older Version of this app is on AppStore and working perfect. The same error is also there, but it clears the review process of apple. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: This happens often with the Swift compiler.  Usually, it's because it's unable to infer a type, and blows its stack trying.

Comment: Often he source for the issue that's crashing the compiler is present in that greenish area of information, skim though it and see if there's some info available :)

Comment: i tried to check out the green part but i didn't get anything @donnywals So how to solve it@Avi

Comment: Just so you know, "only sometimes" is typical with undefined behavior, which a segmentation fault is an example of. If the code is doing something for which no behavior is defined, it "is legal for the compiler to make demons fly out of your nose" (that is, cause anything to happen). It may work, it may throw a segfault, or it may dance on the rooftops in its knickers.

Comment: So what's the solution for this. @CodeMouse92

Comment: If I knew that, I would have answered. I'm not familiar enough with XCode to be able to diagnose this. I just wanted to share the information I did have. You'll need to trust that, as soon as someone knows the solution to this, they will answer.

Comment: Thnx for the information @CodeMouse92

Comment: By the way, have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557581/command-failed-due-to-signal-segmentation-fault-11?rq=1)?

Comment: Yes i read this but I thought if other solution is possible and other thing is that sometimes it build. So i ask the question. @CodeMouse92

Comment: Well, again, you have undefined behavior. The fact that you only get a segmentation fault *sometimes* doesn't differentiate your problem from that question. Have you looked into each any every answer there? (There are two pages of them).

Comment: Yes i looked all but nothing can solve my problem

Comment: @DhruvKhatri Have you found the solution? I'm losing my health on constant dealing with that error

Comment: No didn't find solution in my code. but all my search results tell me that assign every variable type. not use direct AnyObject. but it didn't solve my problem.@DCDC

Answer (score 0):

Check your code somewhere you trying assign Inferred type to AnyObject.

**Example**:

```
let urlParameter = "FollowingUserID=" + followingId + "&FollowerUserID=" + self.userInfo![Constants.keyFollowerId]
```

userInfo is Swift Dictionary type. When i tried to concatenate compiler throws segmentation fault error.

splitting above code by typecasting the followerId.It succeeded compilation.

```
let followerId = self.userInfo![Constants.keyFollowerId] as? String
let urlParameter = "FollowingUserID=" + followingId + "&FollowerUserID=" + followerId!
```

Strictly type cast wherever you used AnyObject or not inferred type.