# command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 when swift 3 migration

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

my example code is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-bSY9YevABJZG9KaFJBSnQ5TXc)
and my fault is under the line 
thanks for advices.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is dynamic and each time there is something for which compiler will complain.

I think given line of code in `viewDidLoad` causing problem. Don't know compiler why complaining.

But if you comment this line of code then error will get removed.
Try once by removing this line.

If it works, then try to work around this line.

```
currencyFormatter.currencyCode = (Locale.current as NSLocale).displayName(forKey: NSLocale.Key.currencySymbol, value: NSLocale.Key.currencyCode)
```

Here is [segmentation fault thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557581/command-failed-due-to-signal-segmentation-fault-11?rq=1), but each one has its own solution, there is no universal solution for this error.

Best luck!!!

Comment: Thank you for advice I'll try fastly : ) I am going to tell the result .

Comment: Thats worked fine : )) thank you so much. Take care, have a nice day my friend : )) @technerd

Comment: Do you get solution for that ?

Comment: Yes, I created new class for currency formatter and I called function in there. It' s worked, thank you again. @technerd