# command failed due to signal segmentation fault 11 xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

I converted project from swift 2.+ to 3.0.

I got an error like below.

**command failed due to signal segmentation fault 11**

When i saw error description, it indicates to multiple files. I observed in all files i used **mutableCopy**. If i made a comment in any one of swift file related that can be removed from the list of files in above error.

Please help me in this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

[image: Error Image scrren shot]

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and re building ?

Comment: Yes I did.
But there is no luck.

Comment: Tried this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557581/command-failed-due-to-signal-segmentation-fault-11

Comment: Please paste the logs as text. Please also paste the context of the error, as it doesn't mean anything standalone. Does it segfault after compilation or during compilation?

Comment: The error is telling you that you cannot convert `CGMutablePath` to `NSMutableArray`. Note: In Swift you shouldn't be using NS classes, use the Swift bridged versions.