# Command failed due to signal:Segmentation fault: 11 in xcode 8.0

Tags: swift3, xcode8

We are using realm for local database and we are getting `Command failed due to signal:Segmentation fault: 11 in xcode 8.0` error . I didn't get where is problem .[image: stack trace image]

Comment: It would help to share some code too.

Comment: I have lot of files which one i share

Comment: If this is a compiler error you could take a look at this question  :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557581/command-failed-due-to-signal-segmentation-fault-11