# Is there a way to Catch a Segmentation Fault 11 in Swift/iOS?

Tags: ios, swift3, segmentation-fault

I have an odd problem.  I am rendering an image from the video camera, then later on I am trying to read the color of a pixel from the image.

Most of the time I don't have a problem. But there are times when my project tries to read the pixel data, I get a segmentation fault error and everything crashes.  I think it is happening in the moments when that system is updating the UIImage/Buffer and it is between frames.

Since, it is not necessary for me to have the exact color every time I call getPixelColor(), I figured I could put in a guard statement and just return UIColor.Black.   But since a lot of the extension function is using Structs/Primary/Unsafe types, and I get a error from the compiler saying I cannot unwrap those in Swift.

Is there a way to graceful way to catch this segmentation fault, or do I have to do something else?

This is the function that captures the image.

```
func renderImageFromColorCameraSampleBuffer( _ sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer ) {
    if let cvPixels = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer( sampleBuffer ) {
        let coreImage = CIImage( cvPixelBuffer: cvPixels )
        let context = CIContext()
        let rect = CGRect(
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: CGFloat( CVPixelBufferGetWidth(cvPixels) ),
            height: CGFloat( CVPixelBufferGetHeight(cvPixels) )
        )
        let cgImage = context.createCGImage( coreImage, from: rect )

        // What to use for the system
        self.currentColorImage = UIImage( cgImage: cgImage! )


        // Let the View Controller Know there is a new image to display.
        SRLNotifications.postDisplayCamera(image: self.currentColorImage!)

    }
}
```

This is what I am using to read the pixel data. [From a post on StackOver
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25956283/2011541 ]

```
extension UIImage {

    func getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint) -> UIColor {

        let pixelData = self.cgImage!.dataProvider!.data
        let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)

        let pixelInfo: Int = ((Int(self.size.width) * Int(pos.y)) + Int(pos.x) ) * 4

        let r = CGFloat( data[pixelInfo] ) / CGFloat(255.0)
        let g = CGFloat( data[pixelInfo+1] ) / CGFloat(255.0)
        let b = CGFloat( data[pixelInfo+2] ) / CGFloat(255.0)
        let a = CGFloat( data[pixelInfo+3] ) / CGFloat(255.0)

        return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
    }

}
```

Comment: Your `getPixelColor` function makes a lot of assumptions. It assumes the image data is 32-bits per pixel in RGBA format. There are many other possible formats. You should be using many of the other `CGImage` properties to determine the data layout and size.

Comment: Please check answers on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557581/command-failed-due-to-signal-segmentation-fault-11

Comment: I saw that stack overflow post, but it deal with SegFault during Compile time.  I am having the problem while the app is running.