# When I archive a iOS project, there has a error: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: swift, xcode

MacOS: 10.14.6 - Xcode: Version 11.3.1 (11C504)

I create a demo project in github. if anyone can help me, you can check it

https://github.com/philCc/URLNavigatorExt.git branch:Segmentation_fault_11

```
1.  While running pass #153921 SILFunctionTransform "DCE" on SILFunction "@$s23URLNavigatorExt_Example6RouterO9PRWebviewV8instance2byAESgSDyS2SG_tFZ".
 for 'instance(by:)' (at /Users/phil/Documents/WorkSpace/ky_tech/URLNavigatorExt/Example/URLNavigatorExt/generated/Router.generated.swift:989:20)
0  swift                    0x000000010e1cca63 PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 51
1  swift                    0x000000010e1cc236 SignalHandler(int) + 358
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff5b7bfb5d _sigtramp + 29
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x000000010f830600 _sigtramp + 3020360384
4  swift                    0x000000010a53a370 (anonymous namespace)::DCE::markControllingTerminatorsLive(swift::SILBasicBlock*) + 800
5  swift                    0x000000010a539ca2 (anonymous namespace)::DCE::markValueLive(swift::SILNode*) + 466
6  swift                    0x000000010a5375e8 (anonymous namespace)::DCE::run() + 2728
7  swift                    0x000000010a4bef3e swift::SILPassManager::execute() + 4606
8  swift                    0x000000010a11d96b swift::CompilerInstance::performSILProcessing(swift::SILModule*, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 6379
9  swift                    0x0000000109e15ec5 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 33925
10 swift                    0x0000000109e0a234 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 6820
11 swift                    0x0000000109d97733 main + 1219
12 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff5b5d43d5 start + 1
13 libdyld.dylib            0x0000000000000056 start + 2762128514
error: Segmentation fault: 11 (in target 'URLNavigatorExt_Example' from project 'URLNavigatorExt')
```

if change the line: 993

then archive will be successful

```
var _url: String?
// to
var _url: String? = ""
// or 
var _url: String? = dict["url"]
```

Comment: Did you try to clean the archive and xcode? Did you check possible solutions from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557581/command-failed-due-to-signal-segmentation-fault-11

Comment: I have cleaned up archive and xcode but nothing works.

Comment: May I ask you? Did you try to archive the demo?